# Performance of sorting NSURLs with localizedStandardCompare

Tags: objective-c, performance, macos, cocoa

I need to sort a NSMutableArray containing NSURLs with localizedStandardCompare:

```
[array sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSString *f1 = [(NSURL *)obj1 absoluteString];
    NSString *f2 = [(NSURL *)obj2 absoluteString];
    return [f1 localizedStandardCompare:f2];
}];
```

This works fine, but I worry a bit about the performance: the block will be evaluated n log n times during the sort, so I'd like it to be fast (the array might have up to 100,000 elements). Since localizedStandardCompare is only available on NSString, I need to convert the URLs to strings. Above, I use `absoluteString`, but there are other methods that return a NSString, for example relativeString. Reading the NSURL class reference, I get the impression that relativeString might be faster, since the URL does not need to be resolved, but this is my first time with Cocoa and OS-X, and thus just a wild guess.

Additional constraint: in this case, all URLs come from a NSDirectoryEnumerator on local storage, so all are file URLs. It would be a bonus if the method would work for all kinds of URL, though.

My question: which method should I use to convert NSURL to NSString for best performance?

Profiling all possible methods might be possible, but I have only one (rather fast) OS-X machine, and who knows - one day the code might end up on iOS.

I'm using Xcode 4.5.2 on OS-X 10.8.2, but the program should work on older version, too (within reasonable bounds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I benchmarked the sort. It turned out that `absoluteString` and `relativeString` are much faster that `path` or `relativePath`.

Sorting about 26000 entries:

```
relativeString      550ms
absoluteString      580ms
path                920ms
relativePath        960ms
field access        480ms
```

For *field access*, I put the value of `absoluteString` into a field prior to the sort and access that. So, the `...String` accessors are almost as fast as field access, and thus a good choice for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use Carbon's FSCatalogSearch, which is faster than NSDirectoryEnumerator. As for getting the path, I see no choice.

The only thing you may consider for speeding up the sorting is that the paths are partially sorted, because the file system will return all the files of the same folder in alphabetical order.

So you may want to take all the path of the same directory and merge them with the other results.

For example the home contents may be:

> ab1.txt
>   bb.txt
>   c.txt

The documents directory may contain:

> adf.txt
>   fgh.txt

So you just merge them with a customized algorithm, which just applies the merge part of a mergesort.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the files being returned in alphabetical order? Doesn't that depend on the file system? (Note that a sort is still necessary because localizedStandardCompare is not alphabetical, but a mergesort for example might still be much faster for nearly-sorted input).

Comment: FSCatalogSearch seems to be deprecated in 10.8, so I'd like to avoid using it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any reference, I just tried it and my system returns the files in alphabetical order. Yes, it depends on the file system but we're both using OS X, not sure about the version.

Comment: I'm using 10.8.2, but "local storage" might also be a FAT32 or NTFS volume, or anything else OS-X can mount.